# PHP setting up a function

Tags: php, function

I need to set up a function which will convert random number between 1 and 7 into days of a week for example if the random numbers appears to be "1" it should display "Monday" and same goes for "2" which will display "Tuesday" etc. Does anyone here know the simple way of doing it ? Also later on in the second task i'll have to make all the days of the week display from Monday until a random day of the week(1-7) for example "Friday". Im pretty new to PHP and this got me so confused.

Comment: Look into strftime. This is most likely what you are trying to accomplish. Protip: don't make custom date/time processing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Custom function could be like:

```
function convertWeekday($num) {
   switch ($num) {
      case 1: $result = 'Monday'; break;
      case 2: $result = 'Tuesday'; break;
      case 3: $result = 'Wednesday'; break;
      case 4: $result = 'Thursday'; break;
      case 5: $result = 'Friday'; break;
      case 6: $result = 'Saturday'; break;
      case 7: $result = 'Sunday'; break;
   }
   return $result;
}
```

But you should better make use of the PHP `date()` function.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try this and go from there

```
    $day_of_week = date('N', strtotime('Monday')); {
    echo $day_of_week ;
}
```